# COFF x86_64 relocation types

Tags: linker, x86-64, object-files, relocation, coff

I am working on linker development for an open source project. The target architecture is `AMD_X86_X64`. In `AMD_X86_X64` specification The relocation types' calculations for ELF are declared for example, `R_X86_64_64`
the calculation is `S + A`. How to do these calculations in COFF I can't find them online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COFF relocation types are enumerated at [COFF Relocations for x64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#type-indicators).

`IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ABSOLUTE` corresponds with `R_X86_X64_COPY` (no relocation),
`IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR64` corresponds with `R_X86_X64_64` (S+A),
`IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32` corresponds with `R_X86_X64_32` (S+A),
`IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32` corresponds with `R_X86_X64_PC32` (S+A-P).

Comment: So for `IMAGE_REL_AMD64_REL32_1` the calculation will be (S + A - P + 1).
What about the other calculations ?
They are just enumerated in the docs

Comment: Yes, `IMAGE_AMD64_REL32_x` are used when the relocated DWORD is not the last field in instruction encoding and x bytes follow it.   `IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32NB` (NoBase) is related to RVA rather than VA, Microsoft employs it for relocations in *resources*.
I don't think that the remaining relocation types were ever used.